# Error creating a Web component

Tags: html, web-component

I'm new to Web components and I am trying to create a very simple component to understand how it works. But I have a problem creating one. I followed the steps mentioned in both [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) docs but I still cant create one successfully and also couldn't find the problem.

```js
class toolTip extends HTMLElement {
  var msg = this.getAttribute('msg');
  var value = this.getAttribute('value');
  console.log(msg);
  console.log(value);
  this.innerHTML = msg + ' - ' + value;
}

customElements.define('mdm-tooltip', toolTip);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web Components</title>
</head>

<body>
  <mdm-tooltip value='1st tooltip' msg='this the 1st tooltip created using WC'></mdm-tooltip>
  <mdm-tooltip value='2nd tooltip' msg='I replaced the existing text'>Im the existing text</mdm-tooltip>
</body>
<script src="main.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

This is the error browser throws,
I'm running this code in Chrome V67.0.3396.99

[image: This is error browser throws]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a class, you need to define methods that actually contain executable code. In your case, your code looks a lot like initialization code, so a constructor seems appropriate.

```js
class ToolTip extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        let msg = this.getAttribute('msg');
        let value = this.getAttribute('value');
        console.log(msg);
        console.log(value);
        this.innerHTML = msg + ' - ' + value;
    }
}

customElements.define('mdm-tooltip', ToolTip);
```

Also, one of the naming conventions in JavaScript is that classes should be pascal-cased (start with a capital letter).

Comment: Thanks, it worked :D My bad I missed such a small thing.

Comment: Even after more than a decade of programming, those small things still keep happening :-)

Comment: 1) You must call `super()` in your constructor.   2) You must not try to access attributes or try to set `innerHTML` in your constructor. See the constructor rules below in my response.

Comment: @Intervalia: You're completely right. I tried to keep it a bit more simple to suit his needs as a relatively young developer. But you're definitely right. Have some upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

J.P. ten Berge is *mostly* correct. But... According to the rules of a Web Component Constructor you can not and should not do several things:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance

> **4.13.2 Requirements for custom element constructors**
>
> When authoring custom element constructors, authors are bound by the following conformance requirements:
>
> - A parameter-less call to super() must be the first statement in the constructor body, to establish the correct prototype chain and this value before any further code is run.
> - A return statement must not appear anywhere inside the constructor body, unless it is a simple early-return (return or return this).
> - The constructor must not use the document.write() or document.open(type, replace) methods.
> - The element's attributes and children must not be inspected, as in the non-upgrade case none will be present, and relying on upgrades makes the element less usable.
> - The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the createElement or createElementNS methods.
>
> In general, work should be deferred to connectedCallback as much as possible—especially work involving fetching resources or rendering. However, note that connectedCallback can be called more than once, so any initialization work that is truly one-time will need a guard to prevent it from running twice.
>
> In general, the constructor should be used to set up initial state and default values, and to set up event listeners and possibly a shadow root.

Moving the code into the `connectedCallback` is a better plan:

```js
class ToolTip extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    var msg = this.getAttribute('msg');
    var value = this.getAttribute('value');
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(value);
    this.innerHTML = msg + ' - ' + value;
  }
}

customElements.define('mdm-tooltip', ToolTip);
```

```html
<mdm-tooltip msg="help me" value="10"></mdm-tooltip>
```

But you can also change it to something like this:

```js
class ToolTip extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._msg = '';
    this._value = '';
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return [ 'value', 'msg' ];
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this._render();
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      this['_'+attr] = newVal; // This will set either `this._msg` or `this._value`
      this._render();
    }
  }
  
  _render() {
    this.innerHTML = `${this._msg} - ${this._value}`;
  }
}

customElements.define('mdm-tooltip', ToolTip);

setTimeout(() => {
  var el = document.querySelector('mdm-tooltip');
  el.setAttribute('value', 'Free');
  el.setAttribute('msg', 'I like getting stuff for');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<mdm-tooltip msg="Help Me" value="10"></mdm-tooltip>
```

In this example we use `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback` to see when either the `value` or `msg` attributes change. When they do we re-render the component.

You can also use properties when setting values:

```js
class ToolTip extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._msg = '';
    this._value = '';
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return [ 'value', 'msg' ];
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this._render();
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      this['_'+attr] = newVal; // This will set either `this._msg` or `this._value`
      this._render();
    }
  }
  
  get msg() {
    return this._msg;
  }
  set msg(val) {
    if (this._msg !== val) {
      this._msg = val;
      this._render();
    }
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(val) {
    if (this._value !== val) {
      this._value = val;
      this._render();
    }
  }
  
  
  _render() {
    this.innerHTML = `${this._msg} - ${this._value}`;
  }
}

customElements.define('mdm-tooltip', ToolTip);

var el = document.createElement('mdm-tooltip');
el.value = 10;
el.msg = 'Five times two equals';
document.querySelector('.here').append(el);

setTimeout(() => {
  var el = document.querySelector('mdm-tooltip');
  el.value = [1,2,3];
  el.msg = 'I like getting stuff for';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="here"></div>
```

In this example I added properties for `value` and `msg`. Now, instead of having to use `setAttribute` you can now set the properties directly and the properties do not need to be strings like the attributes do.